# Fetch nodes recursively with Gremlin query

Tags: gremlin, recursive-query, janusgraph, amazon-neptune

I'd like to define a Gremlin query which returns all the nodes recursively till there are no more nodes available:

```py
Node: ProductionEvent
Node: Product
```

What I've tried so far is the following...however, I'm not sure if the output is correct. Also, is it possible to print it out using the tree() function? And can I do the repeat function with the times function to get all nodes?

```py
g.V().hasLabel('ProductionEvent').
                repeat(__.outE('consumes').simplePath()).times(3). 
                emit().dedup()
```

Im expecting an output like this

```py
Product1: consumed <--- ProductionEvent1 --> produced :Product2: consumed <--- ProductionEvent2 --> produced :Product3
```

Comment: The `times()` function limits the number of repeats, in this case to 3. Have you tried running it without `.times(3)`

Comment: It also looks like you are expecting results from two different edges based on the traversal, `consumed` and `produced` but your query only looks at `consumes`. Can you post what your output actually looks like with the query you are using compared to the example of what you are expecting?

Comment: @TimSexton I receive many rows with the nodes:
==>v[9564QTBGLDVF9]
==>v[0481802604-322892015]
==>v[0481802604-322892067]
==>v[0481802604-322893909]
...
I'm expecting something like:
orderID -> producedProduct -> consumedProduct
orderID -> producedProduct -> consumedProduct

Answer (score 0):

I achieved results which am satisfied with. The query is

```
 g.V().hasLabel('ProductionEvent').has('orderID', 'XYZ')
      .repeat(__.out('consumes').in_('produces').simplePath()).emit().times(5)
      .dedup().limit(6).next()
```

From my understanding, the `limit()` and `times()` is necessary in order to improve the query execution time if the number of results is known in advance. And the `simplepath()` ensures that already visited paths are not revisited again.